# PHP get UNIX timestamps on page load and page leave

Tags: php

I have couple of html pages and I would like to save on a text file when the user entered and left every page in a UNIX format with PHP.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$t=time();
$myfile1 = fopen("temp/time.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile1, $t);

header("Location: main2.html");
  }
```

The code works to get the timestamp when the user entered but is there a way to get one when they left?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not with PHP. PHP is only on the server. You could use JS.

Comment: Define "left". When they turn their eyes away from their screen? When they go to another tab/window? When they actually close the tab/window with your page? Your server doesn't really have any idea what the user does after it has sent the HTML to the browser. It could stay there open doing nothing indefinitely, or not. Any attempt to detect somebody "leaving" is imperfect.

Comment: Also, note that in the code you show, the user immediately "leaves" the PHP page, because you've told the browser to redirect them to `main2.html`. So the "leaving" event you'd attempt to detect would have to be on that page. Overall, I think this question is unanswerable in its current state; I suggest you do a bit more reading about the life cycle of a web page, from server to browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use PHP because PHP is server-side and the unload event is client-side.

To do that, you can use Javascript to call another PHP page with Ajax and, in the code of this other page, record your timestamp.

Something like this (using jQuery) :

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/your_url.php',
        async:false
    }).done(function(data) {                
        console.log('complete');
    });
});
```

However, as mentioned in comments, the header function in your PHP file will redirect the user instantly. In this case, the javascript way is not a solution.

If I'm right, you used the header function because you use HTML pages and not PHP. Your PHP is like a middleware before the HTML page.
In this case, you can use the Javascript explained above for the load event too.